# How to send image from Laravel controller to API Rest

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle6, guzzle

I need to take an image from storage in **Laravel** and send it from a Controller to an external API REST.

I am using guzzlehttp multipart but the API didn't  receive the file, returns file = null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I did it a few days ago (taking file from Request):

For single file:

```
public function storeProductImage(Request $request, $id){
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $body = [
              "headers" => [
              "Accept" => "multipart/form-data"
             ],
             "multipart" => [
              "name" => "image",
              "contents" => file_get_contents($image),
              "filename" => $image->getClientOriginalName()
            ]
         ];
    return \GuzzleHttp\Client::request('POST', 'product/'.$id.'/images', $body);
}
```

For multiple files:

```
public function storeProductImage(Request $request, $id){
    $body = [ "headers" => [
                "Accept" => "multipart/form-data"
              ],
              "multipart" => []
           ];
    $images = $request->file('image');
    if (is_array($images)) {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            array_push($body["multipart"], ["name" => "image[]",
                "contents" => file_get_contents($image),
                "filename" => $image->getClientOriginalName()]);
        }
    }
    return \GuzzleHttp\Client::request('POST', 'product/'.$id.'/images', $body);
}
```

Comment: Thanks in a few minute I will try that 

Comment: Thanks so much that save me