# File upload corruption

Tags: laravel, axios, guzzle

Im trying to upload a file to sharepoint

1. Successful try with just axios is the following
   [image]
2. Failure if i upload using Guzzle
   [image]
   [image]

Uploaded file at the end is corrupted

[image]

Comment: Could you add more details ? like the code source of your upload method and how the file is corrupted ?

Comment: File source is <input type="file"> and corrupted just because it cannot be opened if uploaded by guzzle client

Comment: Can you tell us what type of files you're accepting from this request?

Comment: Excel (.xlsx), Word (.doc)

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Don't use images/screenshots for posting your code. There are inline markdown code blocks that support even syntax highlighting and you should use these for posting your code.

Comment: Please format your question better. Write code in code-blocks and try to provide error stacks, logs, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60169312/10625611

Comment: Qumber Rizvi, still corrupted :( i understand that this is simple post which i have already accomplish with axios, but can not with guzzle :(

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you need to modify to get this working (tested on my end):

1. To get the contents of the file, you need `$request->file('file')` and then use `file_get_contents()` on it. You can lose the `get()` part.
2. Make sure you're sending the header to accept `multipart/form-data` too:

   ```
   "Accept" => "multipart/form-data"
   ```
3. Fields `name` and `filename` in a form are two different things. Former is the name of the field while the latter is the name of the file. You need to send both.

Try this:

```
protected function uploadFile(Request $request){
$file = $request->file('file');
$body = [
          "headers" => [
          "Accept" => "multipart/form-data",
          "Authorization" => "Bearer {$this->token}"
         ],
         "multipart" => [
          "name" => "file",
          "contents" => file_get_contents($file),
          "filename" => $file->getClientOriginalName()
        ]
     ];
return (new Client)->request('POST', 'https://.sharepoint.com/...', $body);
}
```

P.S. - You can check whether a file is valid or not using `isValid()`:

```
if ($request->file('file')->isValid()) {
    //
}
```

Official docs on this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

Answer (score 2):

When providing content to be uploaded to `Guzzle` client as string,
`Guzzle` tries to infer necessary information about the file such as [filename](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/1.6.1/src/MultipartStream.php#L90), [content-type](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/1.6.1/src/MultipartStream.php#L131).

You can help `Guzzle` to infer these information correctly to build the multipart request by passing information about about the filename and content-type in the multipart payload.

```php
[
    //...

    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'fileName',
            'contents' => $request->file('file')->get(),
            'filename' => $request->file('file')->getName(),
            'headers' => [
               'content-type' => $request->file('file')->getMimeType(),
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Corrupted anyway :(

Comment: What's `fileAdded.file` that is appended in `data`?

Comment: It's a file object added to <input type="file">

Comment: Methods like `get` and `getName`do not seem to exist. Please refer to uploadedFile class's API  documentation - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php

Comment: `get` exists on the [UploadedFile class in Laravel framework](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html) which subclasses the one you have linked to while `getName` exists on the `File` class in symfony which the `UploadedFile` subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

Add content-type as blob.

```
axios.post(
    'https://sharepoint....'
    ,data.get('file')
    {
        'headers' {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
            ,'Content-Type': 'blob',
         }
    }
)
```

Comment: OP has requested solution for GuzzleHttp. And content is `multipart/form-data` not `blob`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
Remove the `->get()` of your `$request->file()`

```php
//Get the file object from the request.
$file = $request->file('file');

//Make the request
return (new Client)->request('POST', 'https://.sharepoint.com/sites....', [
    'headers'      => [ 'Authorization' => "Bearer {$this->token}" ],
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'FileContents',
            'contents' => $file,
            'filename' => $file->getClientOriginalName()
        ],
        
    ],
]);
```

Comment: $file is UploadedFile object, so it will upload a object instead of file, but event wih $file->get() i get corrupted file

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should store it somewhere in your local server temporarily first, and then you sent that file to sharepoint, deleted the temporary file, I think if you send it right away without storing it, the file will be corrupted. Please try the way below

```
$file = $request->file('logo');
$original_name = $file->getClientOriginalName(); // get original file
$name = time() . '_' . $original_name; // store it in different name so it would not be duplicated
$path = base_path() .'/public_html/your_project/public/temporary/'; // full path of file folder
// store the uploaded file
$file->move($path, $name);
$body = [
          "headers" => [
          "Authorization" => "Bearer {$this->token}"
         ],
         "multipart" => [
          "name" => "logo",
          "contents" => fopen($path . $name, 'r')
        ]
     ];
$response = (new Client)->request('POST', 'https://.sharepoint.com/...', $body);
// remove the file after done
unlink($path . $name);
return $response;
```

Hope this would work for you! Please correct me if I was wrong

Comment: Saved temporary and posted as you suggested, but it didn't help. Also tried others solutions with this temp file :(

Comment: Sorry but, have you checked if the file is corrupted or not when you sent from axios javacsript to php yet ?